# Particle Emitter - Emit Hair from Skin Modifier Faces

Tags: modifiers, hair

I'm modelling a Hibiscus flower, a reference can be seen below.
[image]

The issue is that I'm trying to use a *particle emitter* to emit the anthers from the filament (nontechnical terms: the yellow stuff in the top photo). I understand how to use collections for the emitter objects, but the objects are only being emitted straight up/down from the source mesh.

[image]

I believe the problem is originating from the modifiers and source mesh. As shown below, the source mesh is just a couple lines, which I then used the *Skin* and *Subsurf* modifiers to create the stalk.

So in short: is there any way to have the particle emitter be used *after* the modifiers (so that the particles can be emitted from the surface) *without applying the modifiers?*

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a way, you said you used a skin and subdivision modifier.

Then the following should work:

1. Make sure to add the particle system at the end of the modifier stack
2. In the particle settings look for the "Source" Tab
3. Select "Faces" should be default, and check the "Use Modifier Stack" option.

That should look like this:

[image]

You can use a vertex group to limit which edge(between 2 vertices) you want to grow the hair.

1. Deactivate the modifiers
2. Go in Edit Mode
3. Select the 2 vertices that limit the area of the later hair growth
4. Create the vertex group and assigning it with the weight of 1.0.
5. Go in Object Mode
6. Reactivate all modifiers
7. Go in the particle tab and under "Vertex Groups" select the new created group in the density slot
8. Smile

[image]

Happy blending:)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Happy to help, learned something new myself, win win.